# Changing frames of the tangent bundle with Schwartz functions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let's consider two global frames $\{v_{1},....v_{N}\}$ and $\{u_{1},....u_{N}\}$ of the tangent bundle $T\mathbb{R}^N$.

Now consider the matrix $\{f_{i,j}\}$that change the frame $\{v_k\}$ to $\{u_k\}$ i.e

$u_{k}(p)=\Sigma_{j} f_{k,j}(p)v_{j}$(p) for all $p\in\mathbb{R}^N$

A priori we just know that $f_{i,j}\in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N)$.

When dealing with PDOs (or more general $\psi DOs$) acting on sections of vector bundles of an embedded submanifold $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ it is common that operators of multiplication by $f_{i,j}$ appear in the local expression of a global PDO or $\psi DOs$

Hence if the components of a section of a vector bundle belong to a certain Sobolev space $\mathcal{K}^{s,\gamma}$ then multiplication by $f_{i,j}\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ would preserve the components of the section inside the Sobolev space i.e. $\mathcal{M}_{f_{i,j}}:\mathcal{K}^{s,\gamma}\longrightarrow \mathcal{K}^{s,\gamma}$. This is important when checking that a $\psi DO$ is continuous or not between certain Sobolev spaces

My question is the following: are there some conditions (possibly on the frames) such that it is possible to obtain a matrix  $\{f_{i,j}\}$ such that  $f_{i,j}\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ i.e. the transition functions are Schwartz functions?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure that you want the matrix coefficients $f_{i,j}$ to be Schwartz functions? Since they must fall of at infinity, this means that your frames $u,v$ cannot both be orthonormal for example. It might be more natural to request that the $f_{i,j}$ are Schwartz up to a constant matrix, say.

Comment: Hi Jaap, could you explain a little bit what you mean with Schwartz up to a constant matrix and why it is more natural? perhaps I can relax the condition I am interesting in and this case would be enough but it is not clear to me the phrase "up to a constant matrix"

Comment: I believe Jaap is saying that you should expect the diagonal entries to approach 1 instead of zero at infinity, i.e., the global frames should approach each other as you go to infinity.  Thus, you should ask for $f_{i,j} - \delta_{i,j} \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N)$.

Comment: I am not sure why the moderators rated this questions as not "research level". When dealing with PDOs (or more general $\psi DOs$) acting on sections of vector bundles of an embedded submanifold $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ it is common that operators of multiplication by $f_{i,j}$ appear in the local expression of a global PDO or $\psi DOs$....cont.

Comment: cont... hence if the components of a section of a vector bundle belong to a certain Sobolev space $\mathcal{K}^{s,\gamma}$  then multiplication by $f_{i,j}\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ would preserve the components of the section inside the Sobolev space i.e. $\mathcal{M_{f_{i,j}}}:\mathcal{K}^{s,\gamma}\longrightarrow \mathcal{K}^{s,\gamma}$. This is important when checking that a $\psi DO$ is continuous or not between certain Sobolev spaces. I do not think that this is a textbook/homework questions, is it moderators?

Comment: I suggest you reconsider carefully why you think you need the matrix coefficients to be Schwartz. The need, if any, usually arises when doing estimates. I'm pretty sure that if you examine your estimates or their proof you'll see that you don't need them to be Schwartz.

Comment: @D.Yang: thanks for your comment, however the PDE I am interesting involves terms like $\partial^{\alpha}(f_{i,j})h$ where $h$ belongs to a certain Sobolev space $\mathcal{K}^{s,\gamma}$ over a non-compact manifold. In order to obtain upper bounds for the norm $\parallel \cdot \parallel_{\mathcal{K}^{s,\gamma}}$ on the element $\partial^{\alpha}(f_{i,j})h$ it is necessary to impose conditions on $f_{i,j}$ or on $h$. According to the Sobolev norm I am using, the conditions to be impose on $h$ to grantee $\partial^{\alpha}(f_{i,j})h\in\mathcal{K}^{s,\gamma}$ are rather artificial